# Cut part of XML shape

Tags: java, android, xml, android-shapedrawable

I have a rectangle shape view in XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle"> 

        <solid android:color="@color/lightblue"/> 
    </shape>
```

What I want is cut it in half, so result will looks like:
[image]

Is it possible? And if yes, how do I achieve it?

Note:

1) Adding rotated white rectangle isn't solution. I need to keep cutted area of the blue shape transparent (there are more View layers under it).

2) Bottom left corner of rect is a bit rounded (I forgot to draw it in image above).

Comment: use a `ShapeDrawable` with a custom `Shape` object passed to `ShapeDrawable` constructor

Comment: So I need to create a Shape programmatically (in my case Rectangle), then pass it to ShapeDrawable constructor. That should be no problem. But how do I clip it, after getting this ShapeDrawable?

Comment: you dont clip anything, just draw your shape inside `Shape#draw(Canvas, Paint)` method

Comment: Then I don't know how to make the corner rounded, if I draw it manually with for example Path.lineTo(), Path.moveTo()

Comment: simple: `Path#arcTo`, in your case `arcTo(oval, 90, 90)`

Comment: Ah, well. I'll try to do it, once I'll finish I'll comment here to let you know how it was going. Then you'd create an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Eh, kinda lame question, but how do I setContentView on this shape S? This can be done with View, but class itselfs extends Shape.

Comment: as i said use ShapeDrawable, now you can use it in View#setBackground call

Comment: Thanks, got it now. Please provide some short answer to make it acceptable as answer by me.

Comment: Btw, setting S radius as 4 pixels (converted to DP), created just a very small radius. Compared to XML shape rectangle (thats the darker one, which also has 4dp as corner): http://oi65.tinypic.com/2duf6v4.jpg  .
I would need perfect copy of this XML rectangle corner :/

Comment: try defining `4dp` in `dimens.xml` file and get it wia `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.some_four_dp)`

Comment: you're just wizard, this works perfectly! Thanks alot for help!

Comment: no problem really

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `ShapeDrawable` like this:

```
Drawable d = new ShapeDrawable(new S(Color.BLUE, 32));
```

where class `S` is a custom `Shape`:

```
class S extends Shape {
    final int color;
    final float radius;
    Path path = new Path();

    public S(int color, float radius) {
        this.color = color;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResize(float width, float height) {
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.lineTo(width, height);
        path.lineTo(radius, height);
        RectF oval = new RectF(0, height - 2 * radius, 2 * radius, height);
        path.arcTo(oval, 90, 90);
        path.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

now you can use `Drawable d` in any call to `View#setBackground()`, `TextView#setCompoundDrawables()` etc

Answer (score 1):

Play around bit ,As of API 21 you can use [vector drawables](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html)

Here is what i did, change numbers as you need .
created a drawable `my_custom_shape.xml` as resource file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="45" >
    <group
        android:name="triableGroup">
        <path
            android:name="triangle"
            android:fillColor="#000"
            android:pathData="m 0,0 l 50,100 -50,0 z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

out put:

[image]

and in your `View` set this as backround  `android:background="@drawable/my_custom_shape"`

**Note** : forgot to try use px instead of dp and see will help to keep the same size for every device , try and see

Comment: he wants left-bottom corner to be round, you cannot do that using `VectorDrawable`

Comment: something is better than nothing may be you can round it for him before me

Comment: sure: a custom `android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape`

Comment: Thanks for sharing may be you can post an answer i will be happy to up vote that\ too :)

Comment: Also, API 21 is still quite high level these days. I couldn't use that, even if it would work correctly.